# How to return the same random numbers in this BINGO program, ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to continue returning the same random numbers generated initially, then for the iteration to continue looking for matching numbers as long as a "BINGO" is not found vertically, horizontally or diagonally.

```
class BingoBoard 


    def initialize
      @bingo_board = Array.new(5) {Array(5.times.map{rand(1..100)})} #creates array with 5 sub arrays containing randomly generated numbers.
      @bingo = {'B'=>0,'I'=>1,'N'=>2,'G'=>3,'O'=>4} 
      @num = rand(1..100) #random number
      @letter_index = @bingo.values.sample #randomly generated index to target the elements in the matching index of the arrays sub-arrays.
    end

def generator #generates the display
  if @letter_index == 0
    puts"B #{@num}"
  elsif @letter_index == 1
    puts"I #{@num}"
    elsif @letter_index == 2
    puts"N #{@num}"
    elsif @letter_index == 3
    puts"G #{@num}"
    elsif @letter_index == 4
    puts"O #{@num}"
  end
end

def play #stamps X if random number is found inside sub-array of targeted index.
    if @bingo_board[@letter_index].include?(@num)
    @bingo_board[@letter_index].map! {|el| el == @num ? "X" : el}
        puts ('%3s ' * 5) % 'BINGO'.split('')
          5.times do |y|
            5.times { |x| print "%3s " % @bingo_board[x][y] } #print the sub arrays vertically, with each index side by side, starting with 0 on the left.
            puts ""
          end
    else #prints the bingo_board.
          puts ('%3s ' * 5) % 'BINGO'.split('')
          5.times do |y|
          5.times { |x| print "%3s " % @bingo_board[x][y] }
            puts " "
      end
    end
 end

def run # one method to rule them all!
  generator
  play
end

end

#=> B 83
        #  B   I   N   G   O
        #  X  18  75  83   8
        # 71  22  47  71  86
        #  3  96  50  92  96
        # 31  69  58  53  47
        # 15  78  15  94  47
#=> I 22
       #  B   I   N   G   O
       #  X  18  75  83   8
       # 71   X  47  71  86
       #  3  96  50  92  96
       # 31  69  58  53  47
       # 15  78  15  94  47
    #=> N 50
      #  B   I   N   G   O
      #  X  18  75  83   8
      # 71   X  47  71  86
      #  3  96   X  92  96
      # 31  69  58  53  47
      # 15  78  15  94  47
    #=> G 53
       #  B   I   N   G   O
       #  X  18  75  83   8
       # 71   X  47  71  86
       #  3  96   X  92  96
       # 31  69  58   X  47
       # 15  78  15  94  47
    #=> O 47
       #  B   I   N   G   O
       #  X  18  75  83   8
       # 71   X  47  71  86
       #  3  96   X  92  96
       # 31  69  58   X  47
       # 15  78  15  94   X


    #=>      "BINGO!!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate the same "random" number in ruby, you need to provide a [seed](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html#method-i-seed).

So, instead of using `rand`, you first need to create a random number generator with a seed:

```
my_random_number_generator = Random.new(1234)
```

And then use that:

```
@bingo_board = Array.new(5) {Array(5.times.map{my_random_number_generator.rand(1..100)})}
```

That will always generate the same numbers in the same sequence.

Comment: That worked in returning the same bingo_board, but it did not save the "X"s when an element matched the random number. Any thoughts on how to save the newly marked board after an "X" has replaced a matched element?

Comment: I don't think I understand. If you want new guesses, why are you regenerating the `@bingo_board`? Shouldn't you just create a new `@num`? I think your `play` method should start with generating a random number, not creating a new `BingoBoard` instance for each random number.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense! I am new to ruby so I appreciate the in depth explanation, I am going to play around with it and see if I can put your words into working code. As soon as my reputation is high enough I will up-vote your solution to my question. Thank you so much!